# Vertical Align text in a table cell with padding

Tags: html, css

I have a table with cells that have top and bottom padding of 10px. I would like to vertically align the text in these cells to the bottom, which won't work with the padding rule applied. Any suggestions?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t520n0z4/1/

HTML Code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="paddedCell">Name</td> <!--text should be aligned to the bottom here -->
    <td class="cell">Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="paddedCell">Email</td> <!-- text should be aligned to the bottom here -->
    <td class="cell">Phone</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.paddedCell {
  padding: 10px 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.cell {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Remove `padding` from bottom http://jsfiddle.net/t520n0z4/2/

Comment: And then use 20px for the top instead of 10 top and 10 bottom. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

A solution instead of using `padding` you can set `height` to `tr`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  height: 40px;/*add height*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.paddedCell {
  /*padding: 10px 0; remove padding */
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.cell {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="paddedCell">Name</td>
    <td class="cell">Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="paddedCell">Email</td>
    <td class="cell">Phone</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```